# Tomcat doesn't finish shutdown, I need to kill the process

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-boot

I'm developing tiny webapp (learning project) using Spring and H2 database running on Tomcat 8.0.20. The webapp starts sucessfully but when I ask Tomcat to stop it starts shutdown but after some steps in certain moment shutting down allways stops. I need to kill the process manually. The log is below. Please advise what could be the problem or how to find out what the problem is. Thanks in advance!

```
C:\ApacheTomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.20\bin\catalina.bat run
[2016-07-07 10:08:52,634] Artifact natia:war exploded: Server is not connected. Deploy is not available.
SETENV.BAT
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\Users\Vojta\.IntelliJIdea14\system\tomcat\Unnamed_natia"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\ApacheTomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.20"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\Users\Vojta\AppData\Local\Temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\Users\Vojta\.IntelliJIdea14\system\tomcat\Unnamed_natia/Conf/AudaNext;C:\Users\Vojta\.IntelliJIdea14\system\tomcat\Unnamed_natia/Conf/webPad;C:\ApacheTomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.20\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\ApacheTomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.20\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
07-Jul-2016 22:08:54.467 CONFIG [main] ConnectorBootstrap.startRemoteConnectorServer JMX Connector ready at: service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://Notysek:1099/jmxrmi
07-Jul-2016 22:08:55.237 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.20
07-Jul-2016 22:08:55.237 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Feb 15 2015 18:10:42 UTC
07-Jul-2016 22:08:55.237 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.0.20.0
07-Jul-2016 22:08:55.237 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Windows 7
07-Jul-2016 22:08:55.238 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            6.1
07-Jul-2016 22:08:55.238 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
07-Jul-2016 22:08:55.238 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\jre
07-Jul-2016 22:08:55.238 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_20-b26
07-Jul-2016 22:08:55.238 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
07-Jul-2016 22:08:55.238 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\Vojta\.IntelliJIdea14\system\tomcat\Unnamed_natia
07-Jul-2016 22:08:55.239 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         C:\ApacheTomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.20
07-Jul-2016 22:08:55.239 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
07-Jul-2016 22:08:55.239 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=
07-Jul-2016 22:08:55.240 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099
07-Jul-2016 22:08:55.240 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
07-Jul-2016 22:08:55.240 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
07-Jul-2016 22:08:55.240 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1
07-Jul-2016 22:08:55.240 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Users\Vojta\.IntelliJIdea14\system\tomcat\Unnamed_natia\conf\logging.properties
07-Jul-2016 22:08:55.240 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
07-Jul-2016 22:08:55.241 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\ApacheTomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.20\endorsed
07-Jul-2016 22:08:55.241 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\Vojta\.IntelliJIdea14\system\tomcat\Unnamed_natia
07-Jul-2016 22:08:55.241 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\ApacheTomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.20
07-Jul-2016 22:08:55.241 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Users\Vojta\AppData\Local\Temp
07-Jul-2016 22:08:55.241 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.1.32 using APR version 1.5.1.
07-Jul-2016 22:08:55.241 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
07-Jul-2016 22:08:56.360 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL OpenSSL successfully initialized (OpenSSL 1.0.1j 15 Oct 2014)
07-Jul-2016 22:08:56.749 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
07-Jul-2016 22:08:56.784 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
07-Jul-2016 22:08:56.789 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 2186 ms
07-Jul-2016 22:08:56.845 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service Catalina
07-Jul-2016 22:08:56.845 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.20
07-Jul-2016 22:08:56.865 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
07-Jul-2016 22:08:56.882 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
07-Jul-2016 22:08:56.883 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 93 ms
Connected to server
[2016-07-07 10:08:57,325] Artifact natia:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
07-Jul-2016 22:09:07.327 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] null.null H2 server was started and is running.
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.3.3.RELEASE)
2016-07-07 22:09:08.894 [background-preinit] INFO  o.h.validator.internal.util.Version - HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.2.4.Final 
 2016-07-07 22:09:08.982 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO  cz.ryvo.natia.NatiaApplication - Starting NatiaApplication on Notysek with PID 9772 (C:\development\natia\target\natia-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\WEB-INF\classes\cz\ryvo\natia\NatiaApplication.class started by Vojta in C:\ApacheTomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.20\bin) 
 2016-07-07 22:09:08.983 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG cz.ryvo.natia.NatiaApplication - Running with Spring Boot v1.3.3.RELEASE, Spring v4.2.5.RELEASE 
 2016-07-07 22:09:08.984 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO  cz.ryvo.natia.NatiaApplication - No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default 
 2016-07-07 22:09:09.734 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO  o.s.b.c.e.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@735c8f11: startup date [Thu Jul 07 22:09:09 CEST 2016]; root of context hierarchy 
 2016-07-07 22:09:12.973 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO  o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Overriding bean definition for bean 'beanNameViewResolver' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration; factoryMethodName=beanNameViewResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter; factoryMethodName=beanNameViewResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter.class]] 
 2016-07-07 22:09:14.738 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO  o.s.c.s.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker - Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$268947] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying) 
 2016-07-07 22:09:14.905 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO  o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 5171 ms 
 2016-07-07 22:09:16.340 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO  o.s.b.a.w.TomcatWebSocketContainerCustomizer - NonEmbeddedServletContainerFactory detected. Websockets support should be native so this normally is not a problem. 
 2016-07-07 22:09:17.028 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO  o.s.b.c.e.FilterRegistrationBean - Mapping filter: 'errorPageFilter' to: [/*] 
 2016-07-07 22:09:17.028 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO  o.s.b.c.e.FilterRegistrationBean - Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*] 
 2016-07-07 22:09:17.029 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO  o.s.b.c.e.FilterRegistrationBean - Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*] 
 2016-07-07 22:09:17.029 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO  o.s.b.c.e.FilterRegistrationBean - Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*] 
 2016-07-07 22:09:17.029 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO  o.s.b.c.e.FilterRegistrationBean - Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*] 
 2016-07-07 22:09:17.029 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO  o.s.b.c.e.FilterRegistrationBean - Mapping filter: 'loggingFilter' to: [/*] 
 2016-07-07 22:09:17.029 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO  o.s.b.c.e.ServletRegistrationBean - Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/] 
 2016-07-07 22:09:18.415 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO  o.f.c.internal.util.VersionPrinter - Flyway 4.0 by Boxfuse 
 2016-07-07 22:09:18.810 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO  o.f.c.i.dbsupport.DbSupportFactory - Database: jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/c:/21/natia (H2 1.4) 
 2016-07-07 22:09:18.949 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO  o.f.core.internal.command.DbValidate - Successfully validated 1 migration (execution time 00:00.045s) 
 2016-07-07 22:09:19.008 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO  o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate - Current version of schema "PUBLIC": 1 
 2016-07-07 22:09:19.009 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO  o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate - Schema "PUBLIC" is up to date. No migration necessary. 
 2016-07-07 22:09:19.408 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO  o.s.o.j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean - Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default' 
 2016-07-07 22:09:19.447 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO  o.h.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper - HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...] 
 2016-07-07 22:09:19.807 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO  org.hibernate.Version - HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.11.Final} 
 2016-07-07 22:09:19.812 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO  org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found 
 2016-07-07 22:09:19.817 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO  org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist 
 2016-07-07 22:09:20.425 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration boolean -> org.hibernate.type.BooleanType@6079c98f 
 2016-07-07 22:09:20.425 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration boolean -> org.hibernate.type.BooleanType@6079c98f
 *** Deleted a couple of log lines - type registration *** 
 2016-07-07 22:09:20.785 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO  o.h.annotations.common.Version - HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final} 
 2016-07-07 22:09:21.053 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO  org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect 
 2016-07-07 22:09:21.736 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO  o.h.h.i.a.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory - HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
 *** Deleted a couple of log lines - endpoint mappings ***
 2016-07-07 22:09:30.236 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO  cz.ryvo.natia.NatiaApplication - Started NatiaApplication in 22.902 seconds (JVM running for 37.363) 
 2016-07-07 22:09:30.271 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG cz.ryvo.natia.log.LoggingFilter - Initializing filter 'loggingFilter' 
 2016-07-07 22:09:30.271 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG cz.ryvo.natia.log.LoggingFilter - Filter 'loggingFilter' configured successfully 
 [2016-07-07 10:09:30,410] Artifact natia:war exploded: Artifact is deployed successfully
[2016-07-07 10:09:30,410] Artifact natia:war exploded: Deploy took 33 085 milliseconds
C:\ApacheTomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.20\bin\catalina.bat stop
SETENV.BAT
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\Users\Vojta\.IntelliJIdea14\system\tomcat\Unnamed_natia"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\ApacheTomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.20"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\Users\Vojta\AppData\Local\Temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\Users\Vojta\.IntelliJIdea14\system\tomcat\Unnamed_natia/Conf/AudaNext;C:\Users\Vojta\.IntelliJIdea14\system\tomcat\Unnamed_natia/Conf/webPad;C:\ApacheTomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.20\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\ApacheTomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.20\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
07-Jul-2016 22:26:40.063 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await A valid shutdown command was received via the shutdown port. Stopping the Server instance.
07-Jul-2016 22:26:40.064 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
07-Jul-2016 22:26:40.116 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
07-Jul-2016 22:26:40.167 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stopInternal Stopping service Catalina
2016-07-07 22:26:40.172 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.b.c.e.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext - Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@735c8f11: startup date [Thu Jul 07 22:09:09 CEST 2016]; root of context hierarchy 
 2016-07-07 22:26:40.180 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter - Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown 
 2016-07-07 22:26:40.193 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.o.j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean - Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default' 
 07-Jul-2016 22:26:40.302 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
07-Jul-2016 22:26:40.352 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
07-Jul-2016 22:26:40.402 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
07-Jul-2016 22:26:40.403 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
```

**UPDATE 1:** Here's the process thread dump.

```
2016-07-08 20:32:42
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.20-b23 mixed mode):

"DestroyJavaVM" #61 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000001ff48000 nid=0x4b2c waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"H2 TCP Server (tcp://192.168.56.1:9092)" #38 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000001ff4f000 nid=0x3fb4 runnable [0x000000002b5cf000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.accept0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:131)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:404)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:199)
    - locked <0x00000006c11a9040> (a java.net.SocksSocketImpl)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:545)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:513)
    at org.h2.server.TcpServer.listen(TcpServer.java:250)
    at org.h2.tools.Server.run(Server.java:578)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"GC Daemon" #23 daemon prio=2 os_prio=-2 tid=0x000000001ff46800 nid=0x4b3c in Object.wait() [0x0000000021e8f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000006c10fce00> (a sun.misc.GC$LatencyLock)
    at sun.misc.GC$Daemon.run(GC.java:117)
    - locked <0x00000006c10fce00> (a sun.misc.GC$LatencyLock)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"RMI Scheduler(0)" #18 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000020bb8800 nid=0x2c34 waiting on condition [0x00000000219ee000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000006c0ee6d10> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1093)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:809)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"RMI TCP Accept-0" #16 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000001fa31000 nid=0x39c8 runnable [0x000000001f91e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.accept0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:131)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:404)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:199)
    - locked <0x00000006c0ee70b8> (a java.net.SocksSocketImpl)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:545)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:513)
    at sun.management.jmxremote.LocalRMIServerSocketFactory$1.accept(LocalRMIServerSocketFactory.java:52)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.executeAcceptLoop(TCPTransport.java:389)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.run(TCPTransport.java:361)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"RMI TCP Accept-1099" #15 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000001f9e1000 nid=0x4910 runnable [0x000000002048e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.accept0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:131)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:404)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:199)
    - locked <0x00000006c0ee7560> (a java.net.SocksSocketImpl)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:545)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:513)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.executeAcceptLoop(TCPTransport.java:389)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.run(TCPTransport.java:361)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"RMI TCP Accept-0" #14 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000001d84e800 nid=0x4a68 runnable [0x000000002035e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.accept0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:131)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:404)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:199)
    - locked <0x00000006c0eca7b8> (a java.net.SocksSocketImpl)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:545)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:513)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.executeAcceptLoop(TCPTransport.java:389)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.run(TCPTransport.java:361)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"AsyncFileHandlerWriter-1639705018" #13 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000001d61c000 nid=0x36fc waiting on condition [0x000000001f49f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000006c0f694b8> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque.pollFirst(LinkedBlockingDeque.java:522)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque.poll(LinkedBlockingDeque.java:684)
    at org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler$LoggerThread.run(AsyncFileHandler.java:144)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Service Thread" #10 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000001d584800 nid=0x4614 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"C1 CompilerThread3" #9 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001d533000 nid=0x3924 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"C2 CompilerThread2" #8 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001d519000 nid=0x22ac waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"C2 CompilerThread1" #7 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001d50f800 nid=0x3c40 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"C2 CompilerThread0" #6 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001d508800 nid=0x3c8c waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Attach Listener" #5 daemon prio=5 os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001c34f800 nid=0x4938 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Signal Dispatcher" #4 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001c34e000 nid=0xc9c runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Finalizer" #3 daemon prio=8 os_prio=1 tid=0x000000001c33e000 nid=0x329c in Object.wait() [0x000000001e9af000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:142)
    - locked <0x00000006c0e4f0d0> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:158)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:209)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Reference Handler" #2 daemon prio=10 os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001c337800 nid=0x3e8c in Object.wait() [0x000000001e83f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:157)
    - locked <0x00000006c0d423a0> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"VM Thread" os_prio=2 tid=0x000000000219f800 nid=0x49ac runnable 

"GC task thread#0 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x000000000211e800 nid=0x1fe8 runnable 

"GC task thread#1 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000002120000 nid=0x3cac runnable 

"GC task thread#2 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000002121800 nid=0x3c28 runnable 

"GC task thread#3 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000002123000 nid=0x4694 runnable 

"GC task thread#4 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000002126800 nid=0x2420 runnable 

"GC task thread#5 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000002127800 nid=0x318c runnable 

"GC task thread#6 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000002128800 nid=0x44c4 runnable 

"GC task thread#7 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x000000000212a000 nid=0x3678 runnable 

"VM Periodic Task Thread" os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001fa33800 nid=0x2954 waiting on condition 

JNI global references: 293
```

Comment: this is a very old problem.

Comment: Take a thread dump of non-killed process and post it here (alternatively, you could explore all non daemon threads and find hanging ones by yourself).

Comment: I attached the thread dump to the question. I hope it is what you asked for.

Comment: Looks like you forgot to shut down your H2 server

Comment: It's Spring Boot, they write it controls the shut down automatically. And I use DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE in the connection string. http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html#boot-features-embedded-database-support